# Duplicating a row in MySQL without recoding for database change

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following table structure:

```
ID
Field1
Field2
Field3
```

I would like to duplicate a record in the table. The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
DUPLICATE * IN MyTable WHERE ID = 3
```

Here are my constraints:

1. I don't want the ID duplicated.
2. I do not now how many fields or their types are in the table.

I do **not** want to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a select statement to insert rows. If you want to insert a new row with all of the same values, just write a select statement to get the values you want. Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2, field3) 
   SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable WHERE id = 3;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67a59/1) example.

**EDIT**

If you don't know how many fields, an option you have is to use a temporary table. See this [article](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/clone-sql-record.htm) for example. The reason you need a temporary table, is because you cannot simply re-insert the row, because you will have a duplicate key error. So the logic will be as follows: Add row to new table, change the id, insert duplicated row with new id into old table, and drop the temporary table.

Assuming your `id` column is auto_increment, you can set the new id to the current maximum id + 1. You don't have to do that, but as long as you have some way of updating the id to something that *does not already exist*, this will work. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 3;
UPDATE temp SET id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM myTable) + 1;
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM temp;
DROP TABLE temp;
```

Here is another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c8ff/1) example.

Comment: How do you make SQL fiddles so quickly? It takes me forever to create tables and insert random values and stuff...

Comment: @Shahar I answer a lot of MySQL questions, so it's become habit haha. ctrl+c and ctrl+v are your friends.

Comment: @Shahar Also the _Text to DDL_ window is friendly.

Comment: @McAdam331 Completely off-topic question here, but I read your profile and I saw that you're a student. Are you a student in ECE or software engineering? Just wondering because I'm studying ECE and there's almost no programming involved.

Comment: @Shahar  my declared major is Computer Engineering, but my specialization is more on the Software side, so I have taken CS electives and I do *a lot* of Android programming in my free time. Also, I deal with MySQL at work and of course, I learn a lot by participating here on Stack.

Comment: @McAdam331 Oh, alright. I see. So I'm on a similar route, I guess. Happy programming~

Comment: Not a problem. Anytime you have questions or just want to chat, let me know!

Comment: @JVMX is `id` an auto_incremented column?

Comment: @JVMX I have edited my answer, please see the revision.

Comment: ID is an auto incremented column.

Comment: @JVMX so does the above solution work for what you need?